# Azure AD App Requires Full Path for Reply Url?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I'm seeing something weird that I've not run across before.  I've got a web app and I redirect in that web app to Azure AD to get a code that I can exchange for an access token.  I've done this many times before so I'm just reusing the same code.  I've created my app registration in Azure, just as I've done many times before.  The problem is this - normally I can just put a host name for a Reply Url in the app configuration and then Azure AD is fine redirecting anywhere to that host.

For example, if I want to redirect to https://foo/users/processcode, I can normally just put a ReplyUrl of https://foo and it all works fine.  In this one case, it says "'https://foo/users/processcode' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application blah".  If I put in the fully qualified path for the ReplyUrl then it works, but for a variety of reasons that are beyond the scope here I don't want to do that.

So I'm not following why it might have a problem in this case.  Wondering if anyone has seen or knows why this might be an issue all of the sudden.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The Redirect URL/ Reply URL has to match the exact page you want to be redirected to. You can add multiple redirect URLs to your application registration information if you want to redirect to different pages in your web site - or your web page could make the redirection for you.

Another option is to add a * in a redirect url as well (https://mywebsite.com/*) - but this only works with non-converged applications.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but...maybe I didn't explain it well enough. The ReplyUrl needs to match exactly only in your code that redirects to the oauth endpoint to get a token (i.e. the redirect_uri param). The ReplyUrl in your Azure application does not - or it least it never has until this one app.  I have many apps registered in AD this way, and as long as the redirect_uri points back to the host in one of the ReplyUrl values it works.  Until now.

Comment: Hi Steve.
How did you resolve this issue. I am also facing the same.